# ASP NET MVC Route - Not Found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I'm having problems when using this route:

```
routes.MapRoute("ProductIndex", "pr-{key}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Product" });
```

When the key contains 'pr-', the route doesn't work.

Example: http://.../pr-my-product-key-with-pr-key

Comment: I tested this in MVC3 and MVC4 and this type of route works.

Answer (score 1):

Routes don't work the way you want them to work, but it's easily **converted**

change your route to:

```
routes.MapRoute(
     "ProductIndex", 
     "pr/{key}", 
      new { controller = "Home", action = "Product" });
```

and use:

```
http://.../pr/my-product-key-with-pr-key
```

or, if you really want to use that "way" you need to override the Initialization method of your main controller are check the link with `StartWith()` and redirect to the proper Controller.